# Test-path checking for access with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find out who on my network has Access installed. I have had several problems getting the list to work correctly, so I have used the output txt file.  Anyway even if it's not a great way to do this it should still work.  Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

```
$Computers = Get-QADComputer | select name | Out-File "c:\access_search.txt"
$Computers = Get-Content "c:\access_search.txt"
$Path = "\c$\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\Access.pip"
$AccessPath = "\\" + $PCName + $Path
Foreach ($PCname in $Computers){
$Result = Test-Path $AccessPath
if ($Result -eq "True")
{$Pcname}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not testing the correct path since it's being assigned prior to the `foreach` loop where you define `$PCname`.  This means that you're testing the path `\\\c$\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\Access.pip` every time.

Try this:

```
$Computers = Get-QADComputer | select name | Out-File "c:\access_search.txt"
$Computers = Get-Content "c:\access_search.txt"
$Path = "\c$\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\Access.pip"
Foreach ($PCname in $Computers){
    $AccessPath = "\\" + $PCName + $Path
    $Result = Test-Path $AccessPath
    if ($Result -eq "True")
        {$Pcname}
}
```

Comment: This worked for my situation. I hate that i missed something so simple. Thank you

Comment: Bah, don't sweat it!  If I had half a penny for every time I needed another pair of eyes....

Answer (score 2):

While the approach of checking for a specific file might work in some cases, it doesn't account for either the file existing, but is not installed; or Access being installed but in a different location.

To avoid both of these WMI can be used (including remotely) to read the MSI data directly.

```
gwmi -comp ComputerNameGoesHere WIn32_SoftwareFeature -filter "name like 'access%' and productname like 'microsoft%'" |
  fl Name,ProductName,Version,Vendor
```

returned multiple results on each of two computers with Access (2010, one x86 once x64, as part of Office Professional Plus) and no results on a system without Office installed. Filter rules might need adjustments for a standalone Access install or earlier versions.

Comment: +1 This is a much better way of accomplishing this

Comment: This does not return the computer name. This may not be the correct way to do this but if anyone is wanting to hack at this script I added a property that returns the pcname, and the search for access returned 12 results per computer with office plus, so i narrowed the search.                            `$Result = gwmi -comp ComputerNameGoesHere WIn32_SoftwareFeature -filter "name like 'ACCESSFiles' and productname like 'microsoft%'" 
$Result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PcName -Value $PCname
$Result |format-List pcname, Productname, Version`

Comment: @Brandan: First the computer name is the `__SERVER` property on the returned objects. Second computer name is an input parameter, to wrap this in a `IsAccessInstalled` function, it just needs a `$true`/`$false` return based on whether any objects are found.